# sql functions and WHERE clause

Tags: sql

Is the function in the `SELECT` clause takes the `WHERE` clause in account?

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM Person
WHERE age > 18
```

will print the count of all persons, or only persons that have an age older than 18 years?

Comment: Only persons older than 18.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 2):

This query will return the count of rows where age > 18

Answer (score 1):

Where clause specifies a condition that tells which rows to retrieve from the table. Since the condition is age>18 it will return the rows whose age column has a value greater than 18. Ṭhe function uses only those rows. Read more about select statement and different parts in it here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29